# Span (column) and rank of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm given a matrix B that's 4 by 4, and in RREF there are only three pivot / 3 non-zero rows. That means the rank of this matrix is 3. Does that mean the column of B spans $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Yes, or something isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @JoyJin No, it does not make sense to say that the columns of $B$ span $\Bbb R^3$ since those columns are not elements of $\Bbb R^3$. However, we can say that the span of the columns of $B$ is 3-dimensional